# Where can I ask questions on Stack Exchange about certain items I wish to purchase?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

On which Stack Exchange site can I ask questions like

Where can I find this product from a store?
Does this item exist?

For example, I am looking for a 500-page notebook (not journal, similar to those 5-star notebooks) I don't know where to ask if this exists and where could I find it.